# ¿Como obtener las ultimas 5 semanas ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
    SELECT FECHA_MUESTRA DIA,
         LABEL,
         DL_OUT_TH_KBPS,
         UL_INC_TH_KBPS,
         ROUND ( (DL_OUT_TH_KBPS + UL_INC_TH_KBPS) / (1000 * 1000), 2)
            TOTAL_DL_UL_GBPS
    FROM V_GF_DATA_GW_TH_KBPS
   WHERE FECHA_MUESTRA >= trunc(sysdate,'iw')
ORDER BY FECHA_MUESTRA ASC, label ASC
```

En donde me trae la data de la semana en curso, lo que quiero hacer ahora poder traerme la data de las ultimas 5 semanas

Adjunto imagen del resultado de la consulta actual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede restar las cantidad de días de las 5 semanas y luego usar TRUNC:

```
FECHA_MUESTRA >= TRUNC((SYSDATE-(35)),'iw')
```

Saludos.

Comment: Recuerde que 'iw' lo llevara al inicio de la semana.

Comment: Como asi amigo, no entiendo muy bien tu respuesta

Comment: Si lo del 'iw' si lo tengo claro, lo que no logro es sacar las ultimas 5 semanas

Comment: select TRUNC((SYSDATE-(35)),'iw') from dual el resultado que me arroja es este: 03/12/2018

Comment: Si a SYSDATE  le resta las 5 semanas (5 * 7(dias por semana)) le devolverá otra fecha que seria en todo caso exactamente 5 semanas a tras. Esa seria la expresión que se debería usar en el WHERE de su sentencia.

Comment: Ya, y como podria hacer para que solo me tomes los registros de esas 5 semanas y no la semana que esta en curso ?

Comment: Si desea omitir las semana actual agrega una nueva condición: AND FECHA_MUESTRA < TRUNC(SYSDATE,'iw')

Comment: Vale, lo voy a probar gracias amigo